# UDP Packets from iPhone could not be captured in Charles Web Proxy Tool

Tags: iphone, networking, network-programming, udp, charles-proxy

**What i am doing ?**
 I am testing an application installed on iphone device. In the application, a Voice Call happens over internet. I routed the traffic in my iphone device through the Charles web proxy tool installed in MAC machine using Proxy settings in device Settings -> WIFI option.

I turned WIFI on and started Charles in MAC machine. Now, i launched the application and clicked on the button to make a call. Call is established successfully. (I am in Network coverage area)

I Closed the charles in MAC machine. I launched Safari on iphone device and entered an URL. I get a message "No network available". But the Voice call is still continuing. I can hear the speaker at othe end even while this condition.

**What is my assumption?**

From this case, i understand that iphone device could not connect to internet.

**What is my conclusion?**

1. From this case, i understand that the Voice call which is happening over internet using UDP protocol will not be routed through Charles web proxy tool even if i set the proxy settings on the iphone device.
2. Charles web proxy tool can listen only to TCP connection.

**What is my question?**

1. My conclusion 1 and 2 is it correct?
2. If UDP packets can be monitored using Charles, how can i do it?

Comment: Do you solve the problem?

Comment: @sahara108, I tried the solution proposed but could not implement successfully.

Comment: any solution at 2017 @Prem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the Proxy Settings on your iPhone (Or any device) only redirects **web traffic** (HTTP, HTTPS) to the proxy of your choosing. It will not redirect any other kind of traffic. To do that you will need to either configure the iPhone with a SOCKS proxy (Will redirect all traffic) or intercept the traffic elsewhere, such as at your wifi router.

Comment: Thanks Richmond. Your answer clarifies my doubt on if the UDP packet is routed through charles or not. I understand the answer is "No". 
Now, From this link, http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/port-forwarding/
i understand that charles can be used to listen UDP traffic. Need some pointers on how to do this

Comment: Configure your iPhone with a SOCKS proxy address of your Charles device and it will work.

Comment: To configure SOCKS proxy. I tried the below steps.
1. In MAC machine, Connected to WIFI.
2. Launched Charles in MAC machine.
Default - Charles runs in HTTP mode. 
3. In iphone, Settings - WIFI - Choose the same wifi - Click Manual in proxy settings and entered Charles IP address and port no 8888
4. HTTP traffic routed successfully.
5. Now in Charles, Set Proxy Settings -> Enable SOCKS Mode -> Click Ok.
6. In mobile, no web page is rendered. 
Kindly help me figure out what is missing.

Comment: In iphone, wifi proxy options, changed port number to 8889

Comment: No you need to setup a SOCKS proxy on the iPhone in a special way. Do some googling research on it.